# Tools to study positions with partial information?

Tags: engines, analysis, learning, software, study

**TL;DR** Is there a chess engine or other tools to study a "position" where the exact location of certain pieces is not known?

From the following chess position, a plan could be to win the a2 pawn in three moves with either a skewer or a fork in the seventh rank, and then win the QPPPK v QK endgame.

```
[Title ""]
[FEN "8/5pk1/4p2p/2Q5/8/6q1/P7/6K1 w - - 0 42"]
[StartFlipped "1"]

1. Kf1 (1. Kh1 Qe1+ {fork next}) Qf3+ 2. Ke1 (2. Kg1 Qd1+ {fork next}) Qh1+ {skewer next}
```

However, then white will be on the move, and we have to analyze whether there is or not a perpetual. The diagram below represents the 12 different positions we will have to analyze.

```
[Title ""]
[FEN "8/5pk1/4p2p/2Q5/8/2KKKKKK/q7/2KKKKKK w - - 0 44"]
[StartFlipped "1"]
```

Of course, since the 12 positions are similar, their analysis will overlap with each other. Therefore, it would be ideal to begin with a singular analysis, and only bifurcate it into multiple cases when the white king's position starts to matter.

I usually do such a study manually using the [board editor](https://lichess.org/editor/8/5pk1/4p2p/2Q5/8/2KKKKKK/q7/2KKKKKK_w_-_-_0_44?color=black) of Lichess, while the variations are shallow enough for me to keep track with arrows. Then I switch to a Lichess Study at the expense of having to create multiple chapters, one for each remaining possibility.

Are better known ways to do this kind of in-depth analysis?

Comment: Off-topic: The positions presented here could appear in today's Carlsen game against Pantsulaia after 37... Qe2+.

Comment: With too many time on my hands I would hotwire a generic tablebase and insert special "breakoff" conditions. (Q exchange being one) In this special case, you can run the 12 subpositions through Syzygy. Black always wins.